# Can't cast from View to EditText

Tags: java, android, view, casting, android-edittext

I have `EditText` that is added from `java` NOT `xml` resource . when I want access the `EditText` I get this error :

```
01-13 13:17:22.084: E/AndroidRuntime(21787): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.View cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
```

here where I am trying to access it :

```
private List<Double> getFieldsData() {
    List<Double> data = new ArrayList<Double>();
    for (int i = 0; i < lytContainer.getChildCount(); i++) {
        LinearLayout lyt = (LinearLayout) lytContainer.getChildAt(i);

        View txt1 = lyt.getChildAt(0);
        View txt2 = lyt.getChildAt(1);

        valid = Util.checkValidation(getApplicationContext(),
                ((EditText) txt1), ((EditText) txt2));

        Double val1 = Double.parseDouble(((EditText) txt1).getText()
                .toString());
        Double val2 = Double.parseDouble(((EditText) txt2).getText()
                .toString());

        data.add(val1);
        data.add(val2);
    }
    return data;
}
```

here where I add the EditText :

```
private void createFields(int count) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        LinearLayout lyt = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lyt.setLayoutParams(p);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams p2 = new LayoutParams(0,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams pv = new LayoutParams(0, 0, 1);
        TextView txt1 = (EditText) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.my_edittext, null);
        TextView txt2 = (EditText) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.my_edittext, null);

        txt1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        txt2.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        txt1.setLayoutParams(p2);
        txt2.setLayoutParams(p2);

        lyt.setPadding(20, 4, 20, 4);

        txt1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        txt2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        lyt.addView(txt1);

        View v = new View(getApplicationContext());
        v.setLayoutParams(pv);
        lyt.addView(v);
        lyt.addView(txt2);

        lytContainer.addView(lyt);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks strange but from what I see the error is here:

```
 lyt.addView(txt1); // view 0
 View v = new View(getApplicationContext());
 v.setLayoutParams(pv);
 lyt.addView(v); // view 1
 lyt.addView(txt2); // view 2
```

Your child(1) is not EditText but View. Use child(0) and child(2) instead.

Btw. Why are you doing this?

```
TextView txt1 = (EditText) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_edittext, null);
```

Why are you using TextView here? Do you also need this strange **View v** added to your layout, what is it for?

Comment: I need ti add invisible view to make 3 view in the row. where each one width should in ratio 1/3

Answer (score 2):

In your createField Method you are wrong casting in below line

```
TextView txt1 = (EditText) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.my_edittext, null);
    TextView txt2 = (EditText) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.my_edittext, null);
```

Change TextView to EditText(when You Inflating the view)
//Changes in createFields Method

```
 EditTexttxt1 = (EditText) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.my_edittext, null);
        EditTexttxt2 = (EditText) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.my_edittext, null);
```

Comment: -1 this choice of type is odd and strange; and reflects some confusion, but afaik not causing the asker's problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
TextView txt1 = (EditText) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.my_edittext, null);
    TextView txt2 = (EditText) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.my_edittext, null);
```

to

```
EditText txt1 = (EditText) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.my_edittext, null);
    EditText txt2 = (EditText) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.my_edittext, null);
```